# Simple SQL Server query takes too long

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

This query takes too long to produce a result.

The table contains about 150 million rows, and the query has no missing index.

```
select 
    Number, BankContacts_ID
from
    dbo.BankContactNumbers b with (nolock)
where 
    b.BankContacts_ID = 1234
order by 
    b.ID
    offset 0 rows fetch next 10 rows only
```

Here is the table structure:

```
create table BankContactNumbers
(
    ID int identity
       constraint PK_BankContactNumbers primary key nonclustered
                with (fillfactor = 70),
    BankContacts_ID  int not null,
    Number           char(11)
)

create index IX_BankContactNumbers_BankContacts_ID
    on BankContactNumbers (BankContacts_ID) include (ID, Number)
```

The execution plan is:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJ8S1TiLo

Comment: _"and the query has no missing index."_ - You misunderstand how indexes work w.r.t. `WHERE` and `ORDER BY`. The `INCLUDE` clause does not do what you think it does. You need a composite index... and better formatting of `CREATE TABLE` statements.

Comment: `with (nolock)` <-- **Do not do this**

Comment: BTW, unlike almost every other object in SQL Server, index names are scoped by-table (not by schema or database), so you don't need to include the table name in the index name.

Comment: Try adding the `ORDER BY` column as a key column instead of included: `CREATE INDEX IX_BankContactNumbers_BankContacts_ID ON BankContactNumbers (BankContacts_ID, ID) include (Number) WITH(DROP_EXISTING=ON);`

Comment: Have you looked at the **actual execution plan**? If so: what does it tell you? Can you post it here (using Brent Ozar's https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ )?

Comment: thank's a lot Dan Guzman, It's super fast now

Comment: The execution plan is: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJ8S1TiLo

Comment: Why have you opted for a non-clustered index on your primary key? This seems like an odd choice for an identify column (which is an ideal clustering key). I'd expect that if this were a clustered index rather than nonclustered your query would perform significantly better. In [this example at least](https://dbfiddle.uk/mmTH_ZGJ) changing to a clustered index means you can avoid the RID lookup which is 100% of your cost in the plan you posted

Comment: I don't have clustered PK cause have CCI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existing index on `BankContacts_ID` is useful for the equality predicate but not the `ORDER BY` since the `ID` column is included rather than a key column.

Modify the existing index to add `ID` as the second key column. This way, `BankContacts_ID` can be used for the `WHERE` condition and rows returned in `ID` sequence for the `ORDER BY` without a sort in the query plan. Furthermore, the included `Number` column will allow the non-clustered index to cover the query.

```
CREATE INDEX IX_BankContactNumbers_BankContacts_ID ON BankContactNumbers (BankContacts_ID, ID) include (Number) WITH(DROP_EXISTING=ON);
```

Comment: I just replaced where clause with this: "where BankContacts_ID =12680 or  BankContacts_ID = 126806" and the query is slow again!

Comment: Didn't know we're trying to hit a moving target ;-) To optimize the compound `OR` condition, the `ORDER BY` column should ideally be the same as the `WHERE`. Try changing the query to `ORDER BY BankContacts_ID, ID` instead of just the identity column.

Comment: moving target! :)))